# How do I approximate the variance of a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

I am approximating a 1D normal distribution by performing many samples. I can approximate its mean by simply averaging out the samples.

However, how do I get the variance? This doesn't seem so simple.

Comment: Is it easier if I know the mean before I approximate the variance?

Comment: You must calculate the mean to calculate the sum square of errors, as shown in the answer below.

Comment: @TaylerJones This assertion ("*must* calculate") is false. You can calculate the variance without computing the mean. For example, the sample variance (with the 'n-1' denominator) can be computed from the squared pairwise differences ($(y_i - y_j)^2$), for a vector y: In R the variance can be computed as `sum((outer(y,y,"-"))^2)/(2*length(y)*(length(y)-1))`. Not that I'd advise calculating it this way, but the point is that it's clearly possible without computing the mean, even implicitly.

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you are trying to point out. Yes, one could substitute the equation for the mean into the equation for variance, but you would still need the same amount of information as calculating the mean, which is easier to do anyways. I would argue that in your example, one is still calculating the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have the mean,

1. find the deviation of each of your samples from the mean
2. square each of these
3. sum these values
4. divide by the number of samples you have - 1

so you have the estimated mean $\bar x$ and the samples in the vector $x$

the variance will be:

$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}$

where $n$ is the number of samples

Comment: I'd divide by n-1 instead of n, no?

Comment: yes your right sorry. I forgot about the $df$

Comment: it should also be x-bar (sample mean)-- mu typically represents population mean

Comment: ok, wasn't sure on the exact notation, that's why I defined it.